# Find not works with Shell scripting

Tags: unix

Find command works when executed in terminal separately.. but throwing

> ksh : find : not found [no such file or directory]

when executed inside a shell script.

Eg:

```
find **and** -mtime -1 -type f  works
```

But not when used inside a simple script

Comment: add your code ...

Comment: update your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: have you specified shell to use at the start of script such as `#!/bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

Find the path of the find command using

```
   which find
```

export the path environment variable by appending the path of the find executable from the above command and run your script

```
   export PATH=$PATH:/<path_to_find>
   script.sh
```